# Induction on Recursive Function with a twist

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to proof the theorem that if `n > 0` then `g n b = True` (see below). This is the case, because `g (Suc n) b` only ever calls `g 0 True`. Unfortunately, I don't have that fact in my induction when I try to proof `g 0 b`. How can I finish the proof (what do I have to replace the `sorry` with)?

```
fun g :: "nat ⇒ bool ⇒ bool" where
  "g (Suc n) b = g n True" |
  "g 0 b = b"

theorem 
    fixes n::nat and b::bool
    assumes "n > 0"
    shows "g n b"
proof (induct n b rule: g.induct)
    fix n 
    fix b
    assume "g n True"
    thus "g (Suc n) b" by (metis g.simps(1))
next
    fix b
    show "g 0 b" sorry
qed
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to use the assumption `n > 0` in your induction.

E.g., you may write

```
theorem 
  fixes n::nat and b::bool
  assumes "n > 0"
  shows "g n b"
using assms (* this is important *)
proof (induct n b rule: g.induct)
  case (1 n b)
  thus ?case by (cases n) auto
next
  case (2 b)
  thus ?case by auto
qed
```

Alternatively you may immediately start your theorem like this
and shorten it further:

```
theorem "n > 0 ==> g n b"
proof (induct n b rule: g.induct)
  case (1 n b)
  thus ?case by (cases n) auto
qed auto
```